# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (409) Conflict during scaling of an Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Can anyone provide insight on why Azure would throw out a 409 Conflict when a scale action on an Azure website occurs?  This happens from the API calls to UpdateSiteConfig

Website is in "Standard" mode.  This is happening continously.  Trying to scale from 1 server to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does 409 conflict has more details like operation pending or simply conflict?  Share the site url, approx time of issue and we can try to see what is going on.

Comment: Suwat, if you can share your email here or email me at igor<at>paraleap.com I'll be glad to provide more details, thanks!

Comment: Looking at the log, the 409 errors were due to trying to scale to 11 workers which exceeds 10 max for Standard SKU.   In what manner, the scale up was performed; for instance, using Portal or other tools?

Comment: Thanks a ton for checking Suwat!